# Quanteda dfm_weight() results in relative frequency > 1

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda, weighted

I'm using Quanteda and trying to compute the relative frequencies of specific words in a corpus which is organized by date and party. However, after converting the corpus to a dfm and using dfm_weight(dfmat, scheme = "prop") followed by textstat_frequency, I get scores of bigger than 1.

Here is my code (I also stem and clean my tokens, not here in the code):

```
corp <- corpus(title_df, text_field = "text", meta = list(title_df[,-4]))
toks <- tokens(corp)
dfmat <- dfm(toks, verbose=TRUE)
dfm_rel_freq <- dfm_weight(dfmat, scheme = "prop") 
rel_freq_all <- quanteda.textstats::textstat_frequency(dfm_rel_freq, groups = year)  
# arrange by max frequency:
rel_freq_all %>% arrange(frequency) %>% tail()

 
 
feature
<chr>
frequency
<dbl>
rank
<dbl>
docfreq
<dbl>
group
<chr>
81093   pension 5.802529    1   117 2004
40971   pension 6.117154    1   97  1998
148372  peopl   6.430454    1   220 2014
65747   pension 6.721089    1   138 2002
53303   pension 7.871011    1   153 2000
74391   pension 8.153381    1   156 2003
6 rows
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour: `quanteda.textstats::textstat_frequency(x, groups = year)` will sum the dfm within the year groups.  So your proportions from the dfm are being summed, and these can exceed 1.0.

If you wanted a different operation on the groups, for instance mean, then you should not use a `groups` argument, and then use some dplyr operations such as

```r
library(dplyr)
quanteda.textstats::textstat_frequency(dfm_rel_freq) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarize(mean_rel_freq = mean(frequency))
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I do need to specify the groups in textstat_frequency() because I am interested in the changing relative frequency of a word across years, e.g. was "risk" mentioned more than "solidarity" across years, conditional on the overall volume of relevant debates. Is that not calculable through the frequency? Why is the sum of relative frequencies bigger than one and if so what is the interpretation of them? Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify: some specific words, per year, have a relative frequency larger than 1; some years' words' relative frequency together is over 200. Is this because of a coding bug on my part? If not, how should such relative frequency be intrepreted? Thanks!

Comment: @Rnewbie You’d need to supply a reproducible example for this question to be answered precisely.